# point on one side of the plane in 4D space

Tags: vector-spaces

I'm familiar with geometry in 3D, such as vectors, lines, planes, dot product, cross product, etc. However, things become tricky in 4D.

First, one can natural define a basis in 4D
$$
e_1=\begin{bmatrix}
1\\
0\\
0\\
0\\
\end{bmatrix}, \quad
e_2=\begin{bmatrix}
0\\
1\\
0\\
0\\
\end{bmatrix}, \quad
e_3=\begin{bmatrix}
0\\
0\\
1\\
0\\
\end{bmatrix}, \quad
e_4=\begin{bmatrix}
0\\
0\\
0\\
1\\
\end{bmatrix},
$$
One can define a 4D cube (edge lenght=1) contain points $v$ that
$$ \begin{align}
v\cdot e_1 \in [0,1] \\
v\cdot e_2 \in [0,1] \\
v\cdot e_3 \in [0,1] \\
v\cdot e_4 \in [0,1] \\
\end{align}
$$
Then I am thinking about how to determine whether a point is in side any convex volume (4D). One need to check whether a point is on one side of each plane (of the volume).

I guess a point $p$ and two vectors $v_1, v_2$ (not parallel, both 4-dimensional) define a plane in 4D, but how to check a point $u$ is on one side of the plane or the other side?

In 3D this is quite simple via dot product of the surface noraml and the point $u$. I'm looking for introductions to 4D Euclidean space.

Comment: The boundaries of the volume that you’ve defined are three-dimensional hyperplanes, not two-dimensional planes.

Comment: My goal is to determine whether a point is inside a 4D cube (rotated and translated).

Comment: Do it the same way that you would in 3-D, except that you’re now dealing with two sides of a _hyperplane_ instead of a plane and you don’t have a two-vector cross product available (though there is a generalization of the cross product to $n-1$ vectors in an $n$-dimensional space).

Answer (score 0):

In fact, it's wrong to use planes to be the basic constituent units. Like lines in 2d, planes in 3d, we'd better use pyramids to be the basic constituent units in 4d. It's very natural. And we can determine whether a point is in side any convex volume very easily because we can define the 3d-body normal and dot product is useful.
We need three vectors to define a pyramids and we can get the value of the normal easily:
$$
\[ 
\left|\begin{array}{cccc} 
    \textbf i &    \textbf j    & \textbf k& \textbf l \\ 
    a_x & a_y & a_z & a_w\\ 
    b_x & b_y & b_z & b_w\\ 
    c_x & c_y & c_z & c_w
\end{array}\right| 
\]
$$

Comment: You're correct that planes are not appropriate here, but the solution presented in the comments (use hyperplanes, which are in this case 3-dimensional affine subspaces of a 4-dimensional linear space) is indeed right. Unless "pyramids" is an alternate translation a hyperplane, I don't see how you're approach here is relevant.

Comment: Yes, pyramids means hyperplanes. My English is not very good, please forgive me.